# How to change html style with echo?

Tags: php

I have this part of HTML

```
<li class="cat-item-16"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
```

and I want to chek if im on this page, change link color to green.

```
if(is_page( 112 )) :
  echo '<li class="cat-item-16" style="color: green;">';
else :
  //d
endif;
```

How can I change li style with echo, is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: This should just work. What are you getting?

Comment: Can't you do this with only applying CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one line statement.If changing link color is only what you need.

```
echo '<li class="cat-item-16" '.(is_page( 112 )?'style="color: green;"':'').' ><a href="#">Text</a></li>';
```

Comment: Can you even help me to get style into li and not a, I need an image background, but after 24h without sleep i see only ".'.

Comment: sorry i couldn't get  "I need an image background, but after 24h without sleep i see only "...

Comment: I updated the answer.You can read more abut inline if else block.if you are having trouble in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when page is 112 it gives thge `style="color:green;"` else the html without the style.

```
<?php
if(is_page( 112 )) :
  echo '<li class="cat-item-16" style="color: green;">';
else :
  echo '<li class="cat-item-16">';
endif; ?>    

<a href="#">Text</a></li>
```

You could also try using jquery to add a style to your li when page is 112.

Answer (score 0):

Give styling to anchor tag () instead of li Then the link color will change.

```
if(is_page( 112 )) {
   echo '<a href="" style="color: green;">';
}
else {
   echo '<a href="" >'
endif;
```

That will work

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, `<a>` tags typically have the default blue and underlined style, no matter what the parent is set to, as per this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6kcm/

To fix this, you either need to apply the style to the `<a>` tag, or set the global style on the `<a>` tag to inherit from parent elements. An example of the former would be:

```
if(is_page( 112 )) :
  echo '<li class="cat-item-16"><a style="color: green;">Contents</a></li>';
else :
  //d
endif;
```

You could also assign a different class to the `<li>`, which then specifies the colour of your `<a>` tag in CSS, e.g.

```
<style>
    li.greenLi a {
        color: green;
    }
</style>

if(is_page( 112 )) :
  echo '<li class="cat-item-16 greenLi">';
else :
  //d
endif;
```

Or set the `<a>` tag to inherit the colour of its parent:

```
<style>
    /* Use cauation...this will set it globally! */
    a {
        color: inherit;
    }
</style>

if(is_page( 112 )) :
  echo '<li class="cat-item-16" style="color: green;">';
else :
  //d
endif;
```